# How to use async/await in Dart for parallel processing

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

In C# I can use `async` and `await` to process tasks in parallel. I can kick off an asynchronous task, do other things, and finally await for the asynchronous task to complete.

```
var t = myFunctionAsync();
executeTask1();
executeTask2();
await t;
```

How can I do this in dart/flutter?

Comment: You misunderstood the concept of asynchronous execution. Asynchronous means not synchronized (in any order). But that doesn't mean parallel. In Dart, asynchronous execution is organized as interleaved execution. This is not parallel execution. You must take this into account when you mean (and want and need) parallel execution. Dart uses isolates for this purpose.

Comment: Ha, didn't realize dart is single threaded. I thought that was 1990 thing.

Answer (score 1):

#### Reference: [async-await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)

```
void main() async {
  var t = myFunctionAsync();
  executeTask1();
  executeTask2();
  await t;
}

Future<int> myFunctionAsync() async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
  return 2;
}

void executeTask1() {
  // do something
}

void executeTask2() {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: So it's the same as in c#! Wish they'd put that in documentation! :-)

Comment: Yes, only the syntax is different

Comment: @KaushikChandru "await task3;" is not the same as: "var t = task3; something; await t;"
"something" will run in parallel to task3, not before or after it.

Comment: Turns out dart is a single threaded programming language and async tasks do not run in parallel like they do in c#. Seems that something called isolates can be used to achieve this... https://medium.com/globant/single-thread-dart-what-ccbca2543ae9

Comment: There is no parallel running in dart unless its an isolate. It will only fire the call but execute one by one only.

Comment: @KaushikChandru Again, that's not exactly correct. You can achieve "apparent parallel running" depending on whether the methods are compute-bound or not. In this answer, the async function will start but will suspend at the await allowing tasks 1 and 2 to then complete before the async function completes.

Comment: @RichardHeap I got your point. But he's mentioning task1, task2 and 3 will finish at same point if we don't await a method and await it at last. I don't think it works like that.

Comment: I think that's how it works for multi threaded languages like c#. So if I am say loading users settings from a file and loading some songs into a playlist, I could kick off both tasks and if they take 2 seconds each, it will only take 2 seconds in total as they are done on separate threads in parallel. In dart they would take 4 seconds it seems as they would be done sequentially.

Comment: I am also a unity developer and i understood what you meant but that's not the case in flutter my brother :)

Answer (score -2):

```
void someFunction () async{
  executeTask1();
  executeTask2();
  await executeTask3();
}
```

Comment: Unless I am missing something here, task3 will only start after the task2 has completed. So if tasks 1 & 2 take 5 seconds each and the task 3 takes 10 seconds, the whole thing would take 20 seconds. My c# example would take 10 seconds total. While task 3 is executing for 10 seconds, tasks 1 & 2 would run and they would all complete at the same time.

Comment: @under yes and no - it all depends on whether they are compute-bound or not. If task 3 was waiting for 10 seconds, then yes, 1 & 2 could complete. Remember that there is only one execution thread in Dart so compute-bound methods can't execute at the same time. See isolates for that.

Comment: await will await a function to complete. In your example task1 and 2 was not asynchronous. You can add await if you want to await task1 execution.